# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'. > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:

Tags: android, google-places-api

```
 private ArrayList<PlaceAutocomplete> getPredictions(CharSequence constraint) {
    if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Executing autocomplete query for: " + constraint);
        PendingResult<AutocompletePredictionBuffer> results =
                Places.GeoDataApi
                        .getAutocompletePredictions(mGoogleApiClient, constraint.toString(),
                                mBounds, mPlaceFilter);
        // Wait for predictions, set the timeout.
        AutocompletePredictionBuffer autocompletePredictions = results
                .await(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        final Status status = autocompletePredictions.getStatus();
        if (!status.isSuccess()) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Error: " + status.toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.e(TAG, "Error getting place predictions: " + status
                    .toString());
            autocompletePredictions.release();
            return null;
        }

        Log.i(TAG, "Query completed. Received " + autocompletePredictions.getCount()
                + " predictions.");
        Iterator<AutocompletePrediction> iterator = autocompletePredictions.iterator();
        ArrayList resultList = new ArrayList<>(autocompletePredictions.getCount());
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            AutocompletePrediction prediction = iterator.next();
            resultList.add(new PlaceAutocomplete(prediction.getPlaceId(),
                    prediction.getFullText(null)));
        }
        // Buffer release
        autocompletePredictions.release();
        return resultList;
    }
    Log.e(TAG, "Google API client is not connected.");
    return null;
}
```

After I upgraded play services to 10.2.0, I'm getting an exception like 
`Unchecked call to '`add(E)`' as a member of raw type java.util.ArrayList` in this fragment:

```
resultList.add(new PlaceAutocomplete(prediction.getPlaceId(),
                    prediction.getFullText(null)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Specify the type when declaring `resultsList`, like so:

```
ArrayList<PlaceAutocomplete> resultList = new ArrayList<>(autocompletePredictions.getCount());
```

See also: [Java Warning using Vectors: unchecked call to add(E)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1840590/java-warning-using-vectors-unchecked-call-to-adde)

Answer (score 0):

Go to 
Build->Clean Project
Now rerun the code. It will work.